# How to get css grid masonry layout with equal spacing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

So I have used [this](https://medium.com/@andybarefoot/a-masonry-style-layout-using-css-grid-8c663d355ebb) tutorial to create a CSS grid based masonry layout for my website. I just have one issue, the spacing between my `divs` are uneven, specifically the problem lays in the unevenness of the row gap, and I am at a loss of ideas to figure out a way to fix this.

Below is my `js`. I have made some minor edits such as not using the `imagesLoaded` library but I don't think that makes a difference.

```js
var counter = 0;
    var grid = document.getElementsByClassName("mod_catalogUniversalView")[0];
    var images = grid.getElementsByTagName("img");

    function resizeGridItem(item) {
        if (grid.hasChildNodes('ctlg_teaser')) {
            grid.classList.add('list_grid');
        }
        var rowHeight = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(grid).getPropertyValue('grid-auto-rows'));
        var rowGap = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(grid).getPropertyValue('grid-row-gap'));
        var rowSpan = Math.ceil((item.querySelector('.ctlg_entity').getBoundingClientRect().height + rowGap) / (rowHeight + rowGap));
        item.style.gridRowEnd = "span " + rowSpan;
    }

    function imagesLoaded() {
        counter++;
        if (counter === images.length) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    function resizeAllGridItems() {
        var allItems = document.getElementsByClassName("ctlg_teaser");
        for (var x = 0; x < images.length; x++) {
            if (images[x].complete) {
                imagesLoaded();
            } else {
                images[x].addEventListener('load', imagesLoaded, false);
            }
        }

        if (imagesLoaded) {
            for (var x = 0; x < allItems.length; x++) {
                resizeGridItem(allItems[x]);
            }
        }
    }

    window.onload = resizeAllGridItems();
    window.addEventListener("resize", resizeAllGridItems);

    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (imagesLoaded) {
            $('.ctlg_teaser').fadeTo(500, 1);
        }
    });
```

Below is my `css` for the `list_grid` class:

```css
display: grid;
grid-row-gap: 5px;
grid-column-gap: 10px;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
grid-auto-rows: 10px;
```

Add a few screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I clearly understand you, you need to change this

```
grid-row-gap: 5px;
grid-column-gap: 10px
```

FOR:

`grid-gap: 5px;` or more px if you need;

Because you use different gap sizes for row and columns so you have not same gap.

Comment: Thank you for your input but that doesn't seem to be the problem. I have set that on purpose. I should have clarified, the problem lays in the unevenness of the row gaps.

Comment: Ok. Lets put your code to stackblitz or jsfidle to check your problem.